# Iterating coefficient values using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, calculate-values

I want to obtain all the coefficient values using ModelBuilder in a dbf file.

[image]

I have managed to derive coefficient values but the issue arises obtaining each of the values as a seperate calculate value to be further used in raster calculator. I followed the thread https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-spatial-analyst-questions/using-derived-variables-in-the-raster-calculator/td-p/349351 to acquire the values but no matter what values I put in I cannot seem to attain the second coefficient value. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The values of the output produced by ols tool are in lines rather than what is shown in the first image. While opening the dbf file in excel or in arcgis pro it shows the file has rows and columns whereas on opening in notepad it shows one line with all the values. Thus to obtain both the coefficients I used the same line number but different position number.
[image]
[image]